# magetno 2.1 order creation error

Tags: magento2

When am placing an order (even from admin).. the order is created, but i get the following error:

Order saving error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento_db`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON ), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

any idea how to solve this ?
googling didnt help